# Storing numbers in Core data being reset when saving another page

Tags: swift, core-data, numbers, reset

I am storing numbers in Core data that are added in by the user, these are saving fine when I do it, even when I turn the page it saves when I go back to it. But when I save data on another page and then go back it resets all the numbers to 0.

below is my code.

```
func saveStats() {


            storeTranscription18CW(pageText: self, textFileUrlString: "") 
}
```

And...

```
func storeTranscription18CW (pageText: Any, textFileUrlString: String) {

    let context = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextInputs", in: context)

    let CWConvert = Double(CWeight.text!)

    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        transc.setValue(CWConvert, forKey: "cWeight")


    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}
```

and to call

```
func getTranscriptions18CW () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()
    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults18CW = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

            for trans in searchResults18CW as [NSManagedObject] {
                if let result = trans.value(forKey: "cWeight") {
                    if let str = result as? String {
                        CWeight.text = str
                    }else {
                        CWeight?.text = "\(result)"
                    }
                }
            }
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better
    }catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

get context function..

```
func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    _ = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return DataController().managedObjectContext
}
```

here is the function for the other fields when i press save on these the CWeight.text resets to 0...

```
 func savePressed() {
    if indexPageSum == 22 {
        storeTranscription(pageText: self, textFileUrlString: "")
            saveButtonP22.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            saveButtonP22.alpha = 0.4

    }
```

and...

```
  func storeTranscription (pageText: Any, textFileUrlString: String) {
    let context = getContext()

    //retrieve the entity that we just created
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextInputs", in: context)

    let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    //        set the entity values
    if indexPageSum == 22 {
        transc.setValue(page22TextView.text, forKey: "page22")

    }

    //save the object
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }
}
```

and to call..

```
func getTranscriptions () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TextInputs> = TextInputs.fetchRequest()

    do {
        //go get the results
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

            for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {

                if indexPageSum == 22{
                    let result22 = trans.value(forKey: "page22")
                    if result22 != nil {
                        page22TextView?.text = result22! as! String
                    }
                }
```

hopefully this makes sense and you can help.

Comment: Please show `getContext()`.

Comment: Updated @shallowThought

Comment: That is still not helpful. I could say `DataController()` now. The reason I am asking is that I thought you might use different contexts that do not sync properly for some reason.

Comment: Otherwize make sure `Double(CWeight.text!)` does not return `nil`.

Comment: yes it is strange as I the other ones don't change when I edit a different one. CWeight.text isn't returning nil its actually saving it even when i close the app it still stored it only changes to 0 when I edit a textView on a different page and save it

Comment: I do not understand. Do you use the same or different contexts? Did you make sure `Double(CWeight.text!)` does not return `nil`? Maybe edit the question with more information.

Comment: I have updated the question and added in the functions of the other textviews that once i edit and save clears the Weight.text one. They both use the same get context function